# java ShortBuffer data transfer without entire buffer

Tags: java, copy, overflow, buffer

say if I have a big ShortBuffer with only 5 relevant items starting at position 0, and a small buffer with less capacity than the big buffer...
How would I 'put' the 5 values from the big buffer into the small buffer without getting a buffer overflow or having to manually index all of them?

currently throwing a buffer overflow exception with this:

```
indexBuffer.position(0);
subMeshes.get(subMeshIndex).indexBuffer.position(0);
subMeshes.get(subMeshIndex).indexBuffer.put(indexBuffer);
```

edit:
also please note that I'll need to change the data from the large buffer afterwards so shared memory options like duplicate etc. are off the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your needs correctly, the easiest thing to do would be to set a limit on the larger buffer. When you do a bulk `put` it will only transfer up to `limit` items. You can do this by:

```
indexBuffer.position(0);
indexBuffer.limit(5); // <-- limit to 5 temporarily
subMeshes.get(subMeshIndex).indexBuffer.position(0);
subMeshes.get(subMeshIndex).indexBuffer.put(indexBuffer);
indexBuffer.limit( indexBuffer.capacity() );
```

Comment: I think that may be just the thing I needed to fix my problem. I wish I could tell you for sure but it seems that everything (literally) else in my program has stopped working. On the plus side, I'm not getting that exception anymore. XD  I've literally reverted my code back to the way it was 12 hours of work prior, and still... (ANDROID must have it out for me)